# Environment variable does not get read?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I have a console application in Visual studio. i have log4net stuff with smtp appender in my app.config file. I have set environment variable in my code (i.e. my email address) and trying to reference this environment variable to send email. However log4net doesn't seem to read this value when the application is run.

My log4net:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="smtp" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">  
            <param name="to" value="${EmailAddress}" />
            <param name="from" value="myapp@gmail.com" />
            <param name="subject" value="testing app" /> 
            <param name="smtpHost" value="<smtp host name>" />
            <param name="bufferSize" value="1" />
            <param name="lossy" value="false" />
            <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%d{ISO8601} [%t] [%-5p] %c - %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <priority value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="smtp" />            
        </root>
    </log4net>
</Configuration>
```

In my console app, I have set environment variable something like this:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("EmailAddress", "testApp@gmail.com", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Does anyone know how can I make it work?
Thanks.

Comment: Please run your application with log4net [internal debugging](http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#internalDebug) on and post the relevant parts where log4net builds up this appender. Add `debug="true"` to the `<log4net>` tag.

Comment: Does log4net produce any output in this application?

Comment: Try the [compact parameter syntax](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#Compact Parameter Syntax), too. It lets you write parameters like `<from value="myapp@gmail.com" />`

Answer (score 0):

I see an old [release notes](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/release-notes.html#1.2.0%20Beta%204) for log4net that says you use an environment variable with the money sign and brackets. But I've never used that style before.

```
${AppData}
```

I've used the [percent](http://www.csharptocsharp.com/log4net-configuration-for-rockin-loggin#comment-3) style for accessing special folders and it works. Try it like this with your custom environment variable.

```
%AppData%
```

---

But, I do have to ask why you're putting a "To:" email address in an environment variable? Can't you use something a bit more modern like the built in log4net [Contexts](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html)?